# SQLAlchemy AttributeError: 'AsyncEngine' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I am trying to use the async version of SQLAlchemy in an `asyncio` app. However, when trying to create the tables using `Metadata().create_all()`, the following error occurs

> AttributeError: 'AsyncEngine' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'

How do we fix this problem? Thanks!

```
import asyncio
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, 
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine


connection_url = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}"
engine = create_async_engine(connection_url)
Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
db_session = scoped_session(Session)

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"    
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Store:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.connection = None

    async def connect(self):
        self.connection = await engine.begin()
        metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
        await self.connection.run_sync(metadata.create_all())
    

async def main():
    store = Store()
    await store.connect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

**Attempt #2**

```
import asyncio
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, 
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine


connection_url = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}"
engine = create_async_engine(connection_url)
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"    
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {"eager_defaults": True}

class Store:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    async def connect(self):
        async with async_session() as db_session:
            async with db_session.begin():
                await db_session.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

async def main():
    store = Store()
    await store.connect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'

Comment: You need to use `Base.metadata.create_all()`!

Comment: When you call `sessionmaker()` I don't see `class_=AsyncSession` as one of the arguments.

Comment: @GordThompson Updated question (attempt #2) with the use of `class_=AsyncSession`, still getting the same error

Comment: @rfkortekaas Good point! Switched to use `Base.metadata.create_all`, same error

Comment: You should use `engine.begin()` for `create_all` and not the session. Have you seen [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/asyncio/async_orm.html)?

Comment: @rfkortekaas This helps! Got it working now with `engine.begin()`

Answer (score 12):

Replace:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

with this:

```
async def init_models():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

asyncio.run(init_models())
```

in details:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def init_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

@app.post("/users")
async def create_user(user: User):
    async with async_session() as session:
        session.add(UserModel(**user.dict()))
        await session.flush()
        await session.commit()
        return UserResponse.from_orm(user)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).